# Admob adverts are not showing and neither is the original view

Tags: java, android, view, admob

So here is my code,

```
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    RollingThunderView a = new RollingThunderView(this);
    setContentView(a);
    adView = new AdView(this, AdSize.BANNER, "ca-app-pub-XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX/XXXXXXXXXX");
    AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest();
    adRequest.addTestDevice(AdRequest.TEST_EMULATOR);
    adRequest.addTestDevice("TEST_DEVICE_ID");
    adView.loadAd(new AdRequest());
    android.view.ViewGroup.LayoutParams lp;
    lp = a.getLayoutParams();
    lp.width = a.getWidth();
    lp.height = a.getHeight();
    this.addContentView(adView, lp);
```

I want my original RollingThunderView with the advert overlaying it. What's the problem?

Answer (score 0):

Can I suggest that what you really want to do is to declare an ad layout inside your RollingThunderView and then embed the AdView within that Ad layout at runtime.

That way you will get much better control over the actual screen layout.